# How do you use multiple FB Application IDs within single client using FB SDK 4?

Tags: android, ios, facebook

In versions 3.X of the FB SDK for Android and iOS you could create and open multiple com.facebook.Session objects for different Facebook Application IDs within the same iOS or Android app. This is useful when your mobile app needs to interact with multiple Facebook Apps.

Version 4.X of the FB SDK appears to only allow a shared singleton instance to be initialized with a single FB APP ID, thus preventing a single client from accessing multiple FB APPs

Has anyone found a way to support this?

Comment: Did you check the Facebook official SDK documentation about that. Here is not the place to ask that kind of question. Check this link to make a good format question http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: I did check their official SDK documentation and spent a fair amount of time reading their source. I tried to edit my question to be more appropriate, but maybe it'd be better for me to file a bug or feature request directly to FB.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
[FBSDKSettings setAppID:@"666666666666"];
```

Comment: It's not entirely clear from the FB docs if we can change the App ID after the SDK is initialized. For my case, I couldn't really rely on this anyway because the component I'm working is part of an SDK used by apps, and I need to be careful not to effect the way the app is using the FB SDK.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving this by not using the FB SDK. For Android I more or less forked the portion that communicates with the FB App. For iOS, I use the Accounts.framework directly. I lose the functionality of the FB SDK that handles logging in/authorizing through a web view, but that was OK for my case.