# Wildcard to add multiple iOS bundle ID on Facebook Developers App?

Tags: ios, facebook

I have many iOS apps that use the same facebook app ID to login. What we have it's basically a White Label platform.

Is there any way for me to add one single bundle formatted as a wildcard? Something like `com.domain.apps.*` instead of having to add `com.domain.apps.app1`, `com.domain.apps.app2` for every single app that I create?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this. You would have to add each bundle to your Facebook app. You can also do this via the Graph API. Please see https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/application/#Updating

Comment: I've never found the API endpoint, that will be great anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you add multiple applications in FB, you will face the following unsolved problem:

[multiple FB Application IDs within single client using FB SDK 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32466685/how-do-you-use-multiple-fb-application-ids-within-single-client-using-fb-sdk-4)

Previously, the problem [could be solved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19455219/how-can-i-use-multiple-facebook-app-ids-in-a-single-ios-application) with the use of a class 'FBSession'. But in the new sdk it is impossible to make.

I think there need clarification from facebook sdk developers.

Comment: I myself have resolved the problem :)
so, right way is: have multiple fb apps for each bundleID